# Copy and delete the file from the FTP SERVER using Windows Service in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a windows service that will ping a FTP site and copy its contents once in every 3 hours.

This service has functions to

1. List all files in the FTP site
2. Copy one file
3. Delete the copied file
4. Repeats step 2 and 3 for all files in the site

Comment: What is your question? Do you need to know how to do it? Do you want to know if anything already does it? Do you want to know what libraries will help you roll your own? What is your question?

Comment: Thanx for your reply,

I need to know how to do it if u have already did is it possible to send the code or just guide me how to do it

Comment: If the above operation is the only thing your service does, it should probably not be a service.  Just implement the functionality you need as a standalone app, and put it in the task scheduler to run at the desired times.  It's a more efficient use of both your time as a developer and system resources (by not having to keep yet another process running all the time).

Answer (score 3):

Use [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx). [MSDN has samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718(v=VS.90).aspx) for everything you need:

[List all files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=VS.90).aspx)

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
```

[Copy one file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711(v=VS.90).aspx)

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```

[Delete the copied file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
```

Comment: it a service where to mention 3 hours time

Answer (score 1):

There are two classes which will be of great value to you for FTP. First, [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) and second, [FtpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx). As for writing a windows service: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560407/c-windows-service-not-appearing-in-services-list-after-install/1560480#1560480) should be helpful as well.

An example lifted from MSDN to delete a file:

```
public static bool DeleteFileOnServer(Uri serverUri)
{
    // The serverUri parameter should use the ftp:// scheme.
    // It contains the name of the server file that is to be deleted.
    // Example: ftp://contoso.com/someFile.txt.
    // 

    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}",response.StatusDescription);  
    response.Close();
    return true;
}
```

With a little bit of work you should be able to modify that to do every thing you need in terms of FTP Access.