# Making exe or msi file of Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, exe

I have made a Windows Service that reads an excel sheet and updates the values in  database. The service just works fine when I install it from the visual studio command prompt.

I have also made an exe file using the other projects option in Visual Studio. When I install that the exe I made, I cannot see my service in services panel of control panel=>System and Security=>Administrative tools=>Service.

Comment: Try to follow this link which has number of link. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3eed40b4-3146-4bd8-ba4f-9c5d142ec21f http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/adminstudio901/Content/ashelplibrary/ISRBuildingMSI.htm

Comment: Do you need to run it as a Windows Service, or can you get away with running the executable as a Scheduled Task?

Comment: Can you check whether service is really installed by accessing Add/Remove programs (start-> Run -> AppWiz.cpl)

Comment: Also check this stack overflow link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560407/windows-service-not-appearing-in-services-list-after-install

Comment: @Kane :I want the installer to be made and give that to my client.So that it becomes a scheduled task.Client will keep the excel file in the desired folder and service will read the excel. As , above the service when installed from VS CMD Prompt runs absolutely fine but when made an executable, gives problem.

Comment: @RakeshGunijan :when i do Start=>run=>AppWiz.cpl,I can see the name of the setup that i have made.Like if my installable files name is setup1, in the programs list I get to see that name. Does that mean my service is installed,but I cannot see the service in services list.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues with production services I've made.

Carefully follow the solution as described here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Note that the key is creating the "installer" service class in the service project. This creates the output you will have the MSI "install" and will specify what account will be used to run the service, etc.

[image]

[image]