# Windows Service not appearing in services list after install using Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

Here is similar question but I am using visual studio 2012:

[Windows Service not appearing in services list after install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560407/windows-service-not-appearing-in-services-list-after-install)

I have installed the windows service using visual studio command prompt, but windows service does not appears in service list .

I followed the first solution in the link above. In Solution Explorer, I right-click the setup project but I don't get "point to View, choose Custom Actions" in visual studio 2012.How i can solve this problem ?Thanks

Comment: Did you trying to install the service with Installutil.exe ? Ar eyou sure you are passing the correct name t ServiceController to start the service ?

Comment: yes .. InstallUtil WindowsServiceHost.exe   is command to execute windows service ..WindowsServiceHost is service project name