# Setup project not correct to install Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, setup-project

There is a number of issues logged on stackoverflow about a Windows Service that does not appear in the Windows Services Manager.
A number of solutions suggest that you use InstallUtil.

When I run my setup project, my service does not appear in Windows Services, but when I run InstallUtil it does appear.

At least that tells me my project is okay, and the problem is with the setup project.

A good post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560407/windows-service-not-appearing-in-services-list-after-install) talks about adding Custom Functions.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and the default InstallShield setup project, and I do not see those options in my project.

Anything specifically that I have to change in the setup project so that it works as well to display the project in Service Manager?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560407/windows-service-not-appearing-in-services-list-after-install

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have done this custom step:

1.In Solution Explorer, right-click the setup project, point to View, then choose Custom Actions. The Custom Actions editor appears.

2.In the Custom Actions editor, right-click the Custom Actions node and choose Add Custom Action. The Select Item in Project dialog box appears.

3.Double-click the application folder in the list box to open it, select primary output from MyNewService (Active), and click OK. The primary output is added to all four nodes of the custom actions � Install, Commit, Rollback, and Uninstall.

4.Build the setup project.